# Reset and Shutdown in pure DOS(not Command prompt in Windows)

Tags: c, assembly, dos, reset, shutdown

In command prompt within Windows restart and shutdown are ok via internal command- shutdown.exe. But for *pure DOS*, is there any way to achieve the same goals ?

- We can assume the platform is Intel chipset and I guess maybe accessing chipset registers is required...

Could anyone give some comments ? Thanks !

Comment: The easiest way to do it from the command line would be fdamp. It gives you all kinds of power management functionality from the command line. http://www.auersoft.eu/soft/

Comment: Thanks for all the information. But what I want might be the interface to the ACPI support in the BIOS or talk directly to the chipset (southbridge) and then hit the sleep state registers to do a power off.   I am not sure if the APM way is OK in current BIOS(legacy or EFI)...

Answer (score 0):

BITD the shortest program *ever* was reboot.com, a 5 byte program that was a jump to the reset vector at FFFF:0.  Not sure if this meets your needs, but thought I'd mention it.

Comment: I found how to reset and shutdown system in pure DOS. To reset the system you can out 0x1 to Port92. To shutdown the system you can locate the ACPI FADT, find out PM1 control register Port address, then set Sleep_Type and Sleep_Enable. Both are tested OK in my platform(EFI BIOS + DOS)